# How to make 2 relations to the same table(using diferent columns) on dataset.relations?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, relation

I have a table clients and a table country, clients has 2 columns referencing country id (id of the country the client is from, and id from the counry the client wants its packages sent to), while dataset.relations is useful to fuse tables using 1 column(or more as long as they are diferent) i cant figure how to display a table that contains the info of the client, and the NAME of both countires corresponding to the ids.

For just the country of the client i go ass follows

```
billOrderDataset.Relations.Add("clientCountryRelation",countriesTableCopy.Columns("id"), clientTableCopy.Columns("countryId"))

clientTableCopy.Columns.Add("countryName",GetType(String), "Parent.countryName")
```

but after that i dont know how would i also add the name of the country to the column "deliveryCountryId" since there is already a relation using both tables and the id column from country, so bascially i would need something like

```
billOrderDataset.Relations.Add("clientCountryRelation2",countriesTableCopy.Columns("id"), clientTableCopy.Columns("DeliveryCountryId"))

clientTableCopy.Columns.Add("DeliveryCountryName",GetType(String), "Parent.countryName")
```

Comment: You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  Both relations are independent so you add one just like you add the other and in the same way you add any other relation.  There's nothing special about this situation.  You should just use names for the two relations that describe their nature.  Just putting a "2" suffix on one of them is and.  The second one should be "clientDeliveryCountryRelation" or "clientCountryRelation_Delivery" or the like.

Comment: I'd tend to get rid of the "Relation" suffix too.  Using that on a variable name to distinguish it from something with a similar name of a different is OK but what's the point of using "Relation" to distinguish something in a list where every item must be a relation?

Comment: What i dont get is how do i specify from what relation im taking the column from, when i do the Add, it takes as param the new name of column, the type, and "parent.thecolumn" but since it has 2 parents(the same twice in this case) what parent will it take, if it took the relation name as param it will be pretty clear to me but it doesnt

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hidden in a paragraph inside the Remarks section in the documentation of the [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression) property.

> **Parent/Child Relation Referencing**
>   ....
>   When a child has more than one
>   parent row, use Parent(RelationName).ColumnName. For example, the
>   Parent(RelationName).Price references the parent table’s column named
>   Price via the relation.

So, in other words, when you have more than one relation on the child table you need to explicitly give the name of the relation in the expression syntax

```
clientTableCopy.Columns.Add("countryName",GetType(String), "Parent(clientCountryRelation).countryName")
clientTableCopy.Columns.Add("DeliveryCountryName",GetType(String), "Parent(clientCountryRelation2).countryName")
```

Comment: This did it, ty